# Replace letters in vectors of string

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a vector of strings and I try to make the following procedure:

1. We have a string in vector[i] position;
2. We pass through the string until we find the end of it
3. Meanwhile we check for specific letters on the string and we replace it with another
4. We're done with that string and move to next one....

My code so far is correctly reads the stings from standard input but for the other procedures I stack. ( The int T you see tell us how big is the vector)

I'm new in C++ so please the answer need to be understanding! :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    unsigned short T = 0;

    cin >> T;
    T++;

    vector<string> phrases(T);

    for (int i = 0; i < T; ++i) {
        getline(cin,phrases[i]);
        cout << phrases[i];
    }

    vector<string>::iterator letter;

    for (int i = 0; i < T; ++i) {
        letter = phrases[i].begin();
        while (letter != NULL) { //while iterator isn't in the end of the phrases[i]

            switch ( letter ) { // we want to replace the letter of the string
                case 'a' : letter = 'b'   //if the letter of the string is a then replace it with b

                //etc 
           }


           letter++; // increase the iterator

        }

    }

    phrases.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **switch ( *letter )**

Comment: @codekiddy is that all? O.o I don't think so. :/

Comment: @Opo: Also in the assignment. `*letter = 'b';` And `letter` shouldn't ever equal `NULL`. It will eventually equal `phrases[i].end()`. `*letter` will eventually equal `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be simpler to use the range-based for statement. For example

```
for ( std::string &s : phrases ) 
{
    for ( char &c : s )
    {
        switch ( c ) 
        {
            case 'a' : 
                c = 'b';
                break;

            //etc 
       }
    }
}
```

Take into account that it seems statement

```
T++;
```

makes no sense.

If your compiler does not support C++ 2011 then you can rewrite these loops the following way

```
for ( std::vector<std::string>::size_type i = 0; i < phrases.size(); i++ ) 
{
    for ( std::string::size_type j = 0; j < phrases[i].size(); j++ )
    {
        switch ( phrases[i][j] ) 
        {
            case 'a' : 
                phrases[i][j] = 'b';
                break;

            //etc 
       }
    }
}
```

Or you can use standard algorithm `std::for_each` providing some functional object for elements of the vector.

Comment: so without iterator? And this will work in all the vector strings?

Comment: O.o I forget to mantion that I work in C++ 98 standarts. Sorry about that. Please can this make in 98 ?

Comment: @Opo Yes it will work provided that you wannt to process the entire vector.

Comment: O.o thank you very very much. As for `T++` that is because my I use `<` and not `<=` but has no change.